# How does vtkImageData store multiple components and how to rendering it

Tags: vtk

I have been doing volume rendering using vtkImageData with one component. Now I want to make a new vtkImageData based on the existing one. The new vtkImageData has two components and the first component store the scalar data the same as the existing one, the second component store the data which I will assign. A fragment of my code is like this:

```
// I read a series of dicom file:
vtkImageData *originalData = reader->GetOutput(); 
int dim[3];
double spa[3], ori[3];
originalData->GetDimensions(dim);
originalData->GetSpacing(spa);
originalData->GetOrigin(ori);

//newData is created based on the originalData's dimensions spacing and origin.
vtkImageData *newData = vtkImagaData::New();
newData->SetDimensions(dim);
newData->SetScalarTypeToShort();
newData->SetSpacing(spa);
newData->SetNumberOfScalarComponents(2);//newData's component is two
newData->SetOrigin(ori);
newData->AllocateScalars();

//Now I have some puzzles:How does the vtkImageData store multiple components, I think it store data one point by one point, because each point now have two components, so it looks like this in memory: Point1(component1, component2), Point2(component1, component2), Point3.... is it right???
//Then I traverse the new data and assign each component of each point
short *originalDataPointer = (short *)originalData->GetScalarPointer();
short *newDataPointer = (short *)newData->GetScalarPointer();
for(int i = 0; i < dim[0]*dim[1]*dim[2]; i++){
    //I assign each point's first component and second component the same data as the original data.
    originalDataPointer[i*2] = newDataPointer[i];
    originalDataPointer[i*2 + 1] = newDataPointer[i];
}

vtkSmartPointer<vtkColorTransferFunction> colorTransferFunction =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkColorTransferFunction>::New();
colorTransferFunction->AddRGBPoint(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0);
colorTransferFunction->AddRGBPoint(60.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
colorTransferFunction->AddRGBPoint(128.0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.9);
colorTransferFunction->AddRGBPoint(196.0, 0.27, 0.21, 0.1);
colorTransferFunction->AddRGBPoint(255.0, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPiecewiseFunction> piecewiseFunction =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPiecewiseFunction>::New();
piecewiseFunction->AddPoint(20, 0.0);
piecewiseFunction->AddPoint(120, 0.1);
piecewiseFunction->AddPoint(255, 0.2);
vtkSmartPointer<vtkFixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper> fixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkFixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper>::New();
fixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper->SetNumberOfThreads(1);

fixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper->SetInput(newData);
vtkSmartPointer<vtkVolumeProperty> volumeProperty =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkVolumeProperty>::New();
//I want to use the first component as the input of opacity transfer function
volumeProperty->SetScalarOpacity(0, piecewiseFunction);
// I want to use the second component as the input of color transfer function
volumeProperty->SetColor(1, colorTransferFunction);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkVolume> volume = vtkSmartPointer<vtkVolume>::New();
volume->SetMapper(fixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper);
volume->SetProperty(volumeProperty);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkOpenGLRenderer> renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkOpenGLRenderer>::New();
renderer->AddVolume(volume);
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renWin = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
renWin->AddRenderer(renderer);
renWin->Render();
```

The result of the volume rendering is diffrent from the result of the original data which only has one component with the same transfer function. Shouldn't the result be the same?

Each pixel has two component, the first determine it's opacity and second determine it's color, how should I do that?

Comment: do you want that each pixel should have opacity variable along with intensity that you will use that for volume rendering purpose?

Comment: Each pixel has two component, the first determine it's opacity and second determine it's color, how should I do @Tab

Comment: usually we assign an opacity level to a specific intensity not to each pixel. you can do one thing that set a new scalar field that will be opacity and set as active scalar field for which you can have different opacity transfer function. HTH

Comment: I'm not clearly. My goal is to divide the data into several sections. I will give each section an unique color and opacity. So each point must have two components. For example, if I divide the dataset into two sections, all of the first section's point have the data (1, 1), and all of the second section's point have the data(2,2). Then I set the transfer functions: colorTransferFunction->AddRGBPoint(1, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);colorTransferFunction->AddRGBPoint(2, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0),opacityFunction->AddPoint(1, 0.5),opacityFunction->AddPoint(2, 1); So first section will be red and translucent, right? @Tab

Comment: do you want something like this http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/Isosurface_and_DVRTorso_Dataset.png?

Comment: this example will help may be http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/VolumeRendering/HAVSVolumeMapper if you are not getting CTF and OTF. well scalar components belong to RGB if you are adding 2 scalar that might not be taken as another data field.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone still cares: You have to switch "independent components" off.

```
volumeProperty->IndependentComponentsOff()
```

The default is on.

Also set the first color function:

```
volumeProperty->SetColor(colorTransferFunction); // not SetColor(1,...
```

from http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/5.10/html/classvtkVolumeProperty.html :

Does the data have independent components, or do some define color only? If IndependentComponents is On (the default) then each component will be independently passed through a lookup table to determine RGBA, shaded. Some volume Mappers can handle 1 to 4 component unsigned char or unsigned short data (see each mapper header file to determine functionality). If IndependentComponents is Off, then you must have either 2 or 4 component data. **For 2 component data, the first is passed through the first color transfer function and the second component is passed through the first opacity transfer function.** Normals will be generated off of the second component. For 4 component data, the first three will directly represent RGB (no lookup table). The fourth component will be passed through the first scalar opacity transfer function for opacity. Normals will be generated from the fourth component.